# Owl Carousel not loading initially

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am initiating owl carousel which gets triggered only when there's an even in the page like opening up the console panel or clicking some other elements.

I am trying this

```
 if ($(window).width() > 767) {
     owl.owlCarousel({
         nav: true,
         navText: ["<div class='de-owl-prev'></div>", "<div class='de-owl-next'></div>"],
         responsiveClass: true,
         responsive: {
             320: {
                 items: 2,
                 margin: 10,
             },
             880: {
                 items: 3,
                 margin: 10,
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

The data for the carousel is rendered dynamically and it takes few seconds to complete. I tried some timeOut but it's not going through. Thanks.

Comment: your code in `$(document).ready()` ??

Comment: Yes. It's in document.ready

Comment: so did you try to change `owl` with the element directly `$('#theElement').owlCarousel ....`

Comment: Yes. The actual carousel is getting initiated with the ID. Since the data is getting populated through an AJAX call, guess the carousel is not firing since the data is not getting populated when owl carousel is ready.

Comment: Yes .. then you need to use the `owlCarousel` code inside the AJAX success function after data appended ..Sorry for my questions But its not clear in your question where you use this part of code

Comment: Will try and let you know. Thanks.